# Python Selenium Send Amazon Seller Product Customization Message

Tags: python, selenium, testing, dom, automation

I am at a sticking point with an Amazon bot I have been writing.. I have read many articles on the potential problem, and I have also tried testing various combinations of workarounds, which have unfortunately not fixed the problem.

The task that I am trying to accomplish is the sending of a post-purchase order customization message to an Amazon seller.  The programming workflow is as follows:

1. Click "problem with order"
2. Click "other issue"
3. Click "Contact seller"
4. Click "Select Reason" dropdown menu
5. Click "Product customization" dropdown option
6. Click "Describe your issue" textarea <-- PROBLEM HERE
7. Click "Send" button

Those familiar with this section of the Amazon website will know exactly what I am referring to.

The problem occurs with the textarea which does not validate upon clicking the send button, however upon inspecting a screenshot the text is visible within the textarea.  I am going to supply the DOM of the textarea to see if that helps anyone provide insight into what may be happening here:

```
<div id="CONTACT_SELLER_OTHER_form" class="a-row">
            
            <div class="a-section">
                <div class="a-row">
                    <p class="a-spacing-small">
                        <span id="CONTACT_SELLER_OTHER_prompt">Contact the seller and allow the seller two days to get back to you</span>
                    </p>

                    

                    
                    

                    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="text-changed" data-csa-c-type="widget" data-csa-c-func-deps="aui-da-text-changed" data-text-changed="{&quot;inputPrefix&quot;:&quot;CONTACT_SELLER_OTHER&quot;}" data-csa-c-id="fetpfe-xkh75w-hthgz8-ywllw">
                        <div class="a-input-text-wrapper"><textarea maxlength="4000" placeholder="Describe your issue" id="CONTACT_SELLER_OTHER_changeBody" rows="4" name="changeText" spellcheck="true"></textarea></div>
                    </span>
                    <div class="a-column a-span12 a-text-right a-spacing-medium">
                        <span id="CONTACT_SELLER_OTHER_remChars" class="a-size-small a-color-tertiary">
                            4000
                        </span>
                        <span class="a-size-small a-color-tertiary">
                            characters remaining
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    
                    
                    
                    

                    <div class="a-row">
                        <span class="a-declarative" data-action="clickable-action-declarative" data-csa-c-type="widget" data-csa-c-func-deps="aui-da-clickable-action-declarative" data-clickable-action-declarative="{}" data-csa-c-id="8mu792-691pf8-tyadjf-wkj88p">
                            <span class="a-declarative" data-action="submit-problem" data-csa-c-type="widget" data-csa-c-func-deps="aui-da-submit-problem" data-submit-problem="{&quot;reason&quot;:&quot;OTHER&quot;,&quot;problem&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;id\&quot;:\&quot;amzn1.pwo.v1.2021362jn4mw8uqqzgnaethmlm8ow\&quot;,\&quot;version\&quot;:\&quot;1\&quot;,\&quot;amount\&quot;:33.95,\&quot;baseCurrency\&quot;:\&quot;USD\&quot;,\&quot;orderId\&quot;:\&quot;112-9877121-7313815\&quot;,\&quot;countryCode\&quot;:\&quot;US\&quot;,\&quot;submittedTime\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;comments\&quot;:\&quot;Please cancel this order. Thanks!\&quot;,\&quot;submitter\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;Claimant\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;,\&quot;customerId\&quot;:\&quot;A152MSST3GCKQF\&quot;},\&quot;marketplaceId\&quot;:\&quot;ATVPDKIKX0DER\&quot;,\&quot;claimantId\&quot;:\&quot;A152MSST3GCKQF\&quot;,\&quot;respondentId\&quot;:\&quot;A1DI45MUWFG9A6\&quot;,\&quot;onscreenResolution\&quot;:false,\&quot;claimRequesterId\&quot;:\&quot;A23ZP02F085DFQ\&quot;,\&quot;avenue\&quot;:{\&quot;avenueCode\&quot;:\&quot;CONTACT_SELLER\&quot;,\&quot;displayName\&quot;:\&quot;Contact seller\&quot;,\&quot;displaySubText\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;actionText\&quot;:\&quot;Contact seller\&quot;,\&quot;postSubmissionConfirmationText\&quot;:\&quot;Message sent\&quot;,\&quot;postSubmissionConfirmationSubText\&quot;:\&quot;If the seller does not resolve your issue within 48 hours of the first message, you can revisit this page to check if you are eligible to request an A-to-z Guarantee refund.\&quot;},\&quot;reason\&quot;:{\&quot;reasonCode\&quot;:\&quot;OTHER\&quot;,\&quot;detailCode\&quot;:\&quot;CANCEL_ORDER\&quot;,\&quot;displayString\&quot;:\&quot;Other issue\&quot;,\&quot;displayDetailText\&quot;:\&quot;Request cancellation\&quot;},\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{},\&quot;changeOptions\&quot;:[{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;Claimant\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;,\&quot;customerId\&quot;:\&quot;A152MSST3GCKQF\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;PROVIDE_INFORMATION\&quot;,\&quot;description\&quot;:\&quot;Claimant changing state to 'ProblemState(csaState=Pending, claimantState=Pending, respondentState=Pending, investigationState=ActionRequired, legacyStatus=INVG)' via HealBeam; reason=PROVIDE_INFORMATION\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;ActionRequired\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:true,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;INVG\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;Claimant\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;,\&quot;customerId\&quot;:\&quot;A152MSST3GCKQF\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;CANCEL_PROBLEM\&quot;,\&quot;description\&quot;:\&quot;Claimant changing state to 'ProblemState(csaState=Resolved, claimantState=Resolved, respondentState=Resolved, investigationState=ActionRequired, legacyStatus=BWDQ)' via HealBeam; reason=CANCEL_PROBLEM\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;ActionRequired\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:true,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;BWDQ\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;Respondent\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;,\&quot;customerId\&quot;:\&quot;A1DI45MUWFG9A6\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;PROVIDE_INFORMATION\&quot;,\&quot;description\&quot;:\&quot;Respondent changing state to 'ProblemState(csaState=Pending, claimantState=Pending, respondentState=Pending, investigationState=ActionRequired, legacyStatus=INVG)' via HealBeam; reason=PROVIDE_INFORMATION\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;ActionRequired\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:true,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;INVG\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;ClaimsOps\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;GRANT\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:false,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;GRNT\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;ClaimsOps\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;CANCEL_PROBLEM\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:true,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;BWDR\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;ClaimsOps\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;NO_GRANT\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:false,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;NOGR\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;ClaimsOps\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;REQUEST_INFO_CLAIMANT\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;ActionRequired\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;ActionRequired\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:false,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;RABI\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;ClaimsOps\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;REQUEST_INFO_RESPONDENT\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;ActionRequired\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:false,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;RASI\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;ClaimsOps\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;RESPONDENT_ISSUED_REFUND\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:false,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;SRFD\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;ClaimsOps\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;SNOOZE\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:false,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;HOLD\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;CSA\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;,\&quot;customerId\&quot;:\&quot;A152MSST3GCKQF\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;PROVIDE_INFORMATION\&quot;,\&quot;description\&quot;:\&quot;CSA changing state to 'ProblemState(csaState=Pending, claimantState=Pending, respondentState=Pending, investigationState=ActionRequired, legacyStatus=INVG)' via HealBeam; reason=PROVIDE_INFORMATION\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;ActionRequired\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:true,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;INVG\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;CSA\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;,\&quot;customerId\&quot;:\&quot;A152MSST3GCKQF\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;CANCEL_PROBLEM\&quot;,\&quot;description\&quot;:\&quot;CSA changing state to 'ProblemState(csaState=Resolved, claimantState=Resolved, respondentState=Resolved, investigationState=ActionRequired, legacyStatus=BWDQ)' via HealBeam; reason=CANCEL_PROBLEM\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Resolved\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;ActionRequired\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:true,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;BWDQ\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false},{\&quot;actor\&quot;:{\&quot;role\&quot;:\&quot;SeSu\&quot;,\&quot;login\&quot;:\&quot;unknown\&quot;,\&quot;customerId\&quot;:\&quot;A1DI45MUWFG9A6\&quot;},\&quot;changeDate\&quot;:\&quot;2021-12-28T06:21:15.238Z\&quot;,\&quot;reason\&quot;:\&quot;PROVIDE_INFORMATION\&quot;,\&quot;description\&quot;:\&quot;SeSu changing state to 'ProblemState(csaState=Pending, claimantState=Pending, respondentState=Pending, investigationState=ActionRequired, legacyStatus=INVG)' via HealBeam; reason=PROVIDE_INFORMATION\&quot;,\&quot;csaState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;claimantState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;respondentState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;Pending\&quot;},\&quot;investigationState\&quot;:{\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;ActionRequired\&quot;},\&quot;commentsRequired\&quot;:true,\&quot;legacyStatus\&quot;:\&quot;INVG\&quot;,\&quot;claimOpsOverride\&quot;:false}]}&quot;,&quot;avenue&quot;:&quot;CONTACT_SELLER&quot;}" data-csa-c-id="o4f6cx-sxrdb0-fnajui-dbrzyw">
                                <span id="CONTACT_SELLER_button" class="a-button a-button-primary"><span class="a-button-inner"><input class="a-button-input" type="submit" aria-labelledby="CONTACT_SELLER_button-announce"><span id="CONTACT_SELLER_button-announce" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">
                                    
                                        
                                            Send
                                        
                                        
                                    
                                </span></span></span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have experience with selenium and have read many possible solutions online which have unfortunately not been of any help.  So, anyone who can provide help into what I am missing, I would be greatly appreciative of.

Comment: What error do you get when you send keys to the textarea?

Comment: Hey @ArundeepChohan,

Something along the lines of, "Message cannot be empty or only contain whitespace."

Comment: Can you post how you sent the keys.

Comment: At this point, my code is a bit scrambled from trying various different techniques.

But, I have tried the following (all without success):

element.click()
element.clear()
element.send_keys('Sample text')

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value='{}'.format('Sample text' )", element)

Comment: I have also tried sending Keys.ENTER, Keys.RETURN, and Keys.HOME at various points which have all been unsuccessful.

Comment: Is there an example url I could use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240496/discussion-between-aaron-phalen-and-arundeep-chohan).

Comment: Please share your code and the error you see in the post. Also if possible please share a link to the page you are working on. Amazom is a public web site, should not be problem with that. Otherwise your question is missing too much details.

Comment: @Prophet, the link is in my order history, so that particular section of the Amazon website is not publicly accessible without login credentials.  However, if you navigate to your order history page, https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/order-history?ie=UTF8&ref_=nav_youraccount_orders& and follow the workflow I have outlined, you should be able to arrive at the location I am describing.  Alternatively, for anyone with continued interested, I can post screenshots to help.

Comment: What about to share your code and the error?

Comment: @Prophet I have to refactor my code after days of commenting out and trying various workarounds which unfortunately none have worked.  

What I will do is clean up my code and post it when I resume working on it tomorrow.

Comment: OK, In case the problem still will be there please ask a new question with all the relevant details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine the cause of the problem I had encountered.  I am adding an answer for anyone who finds this post of StackOverflow and encounters a similar issue.

For whatever reason, the XPATH I had used to find the element had multiple occurrences within the DOM (was not outright obvious to me at the time).  Consequently, when I performed a find_element_by_xpath, I was clicking on the first element in the array.  To get the code to work as expected, I had to perform a find_elements_by_xpath and click on the last WebElement in the array.